# Группировка в sql

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с данными, пусть будет test

```
Id| time   | day                 | task | author 
1 | 10:00 | понедельник | 2      | 102
2 | 13:00 | понедельник | 2      | 98
3 | 14:00 | вторник         | 2      | 98
4 | 10:00 | среда             | 2      | 98
```

Нужно выбрать максимальное время для каждого дня
Пишу следующий скрипт:

```
Select * from test 
where 
time in (select max(time) from test 
group by day)
```

Время в среду 10:00, что является для неё максимальным временем. Но 10:00 было и в понедельник, а выбрать нужно только 13:00, но в запрос попадает и 10:00 за понедельник. Не подскажете в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в Вашем вложенном SELECT, он должен вернуть 10, 13, 14 вот оно и выбирает значения с таким временем

Comment: where 
(day, time) in (select day, max(time)

Answer (score 1):

Проверяя время вы не проверяете к какому дню оно относилось. Надо переписать запрос так:

```
Select test.*
 from test 
 join (select day, max(time) time
         from test 
        group by day
      ) md
   on test.day=md.day and test.time=md.time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Test
AS (
   SELECT
         *
   FROM  ( VALUES ( 1, '10:00', N'понедельник', 2, 102 ),
                  ( 2, '13:00', N'понедельник', 2, 98 ),
                  ( 3, '14:00 ', N'вторник', 2, 98 ),
                  ( 4, '10:00', N'среда', 2, 98 )) Table1 ( [Id], [time], [day], [task], [author] )
   )
SELECT
         [day],
         MAX([time]) AS MaxTime
FROM     Test
GROUP BY [day];
```

Проблемо во вложенном `SELECT`, который по сути возвращает вам набор максимальных велечин. Все что нужно добавить день в вывод.

Answer (score 0):

```
select day, max(time)
from test
group by day
```